# Keep Background Intelligent Transfer Service off

Tags: windows-8.1, read-write

It seems to be starting every single time I boot up my `edit:`**new** Windows 8.1 computer, hogging disk. I went into services.msc and disabled it but it still somehow re enables itself. This is my own computer so no group policy or whatnot. I know it's BITS because whenever I disable it, the disk usage goes down.

I want it gone permanently. Any thoughts?

Comment: To answer your question, change the startup type to disabled. But don't think this is the proper solution to your disk usage problem

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like I did. Doesn't help, re enables itself

Comment: Explain the downvote please?

Comment: It is probably being reenabled by the Windows Update service as BITS is the service that is used to download Windows updates. If you disable BITS then you are, as a minimum, temporarily breaking Windows updates. You'd be better off  finding out **why** you are having this problem than breaking your system dealing with the symptoms. First thing might be to clean your Windows Update data store. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f5744a18-d4ca-4631-8324-878b9225251d/windowssoftwaredistribution-folder-cleanup-automation

Comment: @Mokubai So you're saying if I just let BITS run for a while, it'll finish downloading whatever it is and it will stop? Is there a command to hasten this process?

Comment: @RegisteredUser In theory, yes.  Given time to do what it need to do BITS will finish and everything should carry on fine.  If this is a brand spanking new machine then chances are your system is downloading new updates and sorting itself out, once your system is up to date then BITS should calm down and go dormant.

Comment: @Mokubai How long do you estimate that will take? If that depends on processor, I have a pentium G3258 and 4gb ram and around 700gb of free space.

Answer (score -1):

I would not recommend trying to "remove" it. BITS is required for the Windows Updates service to run. It would be a bad idea to not install updates, especially the security updates. But it probably would not hurt to disable the service, and then enable it in order to run Windows Updates once a month. 
Re-enables itself....hmmmmm, maybe you should disable both BITS and the Updates service. Updates may be what is reenabling BITS.

Edit: be aware that there are other things than Updates that use BITS so you may run into additional unforeseen issues down the road. For instance, I think that certain installations (Windows features, maybe MSI installers) may need BITS.

Comment: The disk usage is probably Windows Updates. Normally Updates can hit a computer kind of hard, but once the updates have been installed and you have rebooted your computer, that should subside. If it doesn't check this out: https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/91738-windows-update-reset.html

Comment: All relevant information should be contained in the answer body. This means external links should be quoted and cited, and commentary shouldn’t be submitted instead of clarifying an answer that has been submitted